# How to pass variables between pages using http headers?

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers

I'm trying to pass an authorization token between two pages of my application and would like to do so using HTTP headers, however my code is not working as expected.

I've tried retrieving the header using getallheaders() from the second page however the header that I pass it from the first page is not present in the list.

This is the flow of what I'm doing

1. Placing token into the header array
2. Executing the POST call
3. Redirecting to second page using header("Location:")
4. (on second page) Checking the headers

```
    //placing token into header/////////////////////////////////////////
    $token_header['Authorization'] = $accessTokenResult['access_token'];


    $header = array();
    foreach($token_header as $key => $parsed_urlvalue) 
    {
            $header[] = "$key: $parsed_urlvalue";
    }



    //sending the request//////////////////////////////////////////////
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "./custom_request.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    //redirecting to the second page////////////////////////////////////
    header("Location: custom_request.php");
    die("Redirected to custom request page");
```

Other page

```
$headers_recieved = getallheaders();

echo $headers_recieved['Authorization'];
```

However I'm getting an invalid index error since 'Authorization' is not present.

Comment: Are you aware that you're calling `custom_request.php` twice? What are you trying to accomplish with this architecture? I mean, why do you need a customised server-side network request to reach a local resource?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thought this was the proper way to pass secure variables? I guess not? What is? Also I can see I'm calling the page twice but how can I send a post and redirect at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean that you use Curl to launch your code because you're concerned that it isn't safe to do it in current script?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, pretty much. Right now I'm using sessions to do that, but I'm not sure its safe? In any case, can you please tell me how to do it properly, as in, how do I pass a variable that needs to be secure (a password or a key etc) within the code. Also I would still like to know how to pass it using a header (just so I know how to use headers from now on). Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's obviously something that's clear in your mind but I'm unable to see. As about passing data through headers, PHP is a server-side technology so you cannot use it to generate *request* headers in the *browser*. In fact, the only way to generate specific headers in a browser is using JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: So what does this line do?  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);? Isn't that putting a string into the header and then sending it with the curl call? Maybe I'm not using the correct terminology? Maybe it's not called a request header, http header maybe?

Comment: Right, there's no browser involved here. The server-side PHP script is talking to itself. With browser I mean Firefox or Chrome. Is `getallheaders()` failing there too? (In any case, I can't give you much advice about this part because it's the one whose purpose I can't understand).

Comment: Ok, but can you help me with what I'm trying to do? If not this way then another way?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm trying to pass a variable between two .php pages on my server, however it has to be done securely, what is the most secure way to do so?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález do you understand now?